# How to pass variables to an intent via an OnClickListener

Tags: android

There are lots of tutorials online on how to pass data in an intent - but all I have found are either trivial (ie they just make up a text string in the intent itself), or are based on view data passed to the OnClick method (eg view.getText())

However, I have variable data not attached to a specific view that I want to pass on to a new Activity, as follows (I've removed some code so as not to confuse, but the loop sets up a list of buttons):

```
for (int i=0; i<menuorder.length; i++){
      .
      .
      String itemName = menuorder[i];

      btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){ 

         //  @Override 
           public void onClick(View v) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
               Intent i = new Intent(ShowSchool.this, DisplayContent.class);
               i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 

                i.putExtra("itemName", itemName);
                startActivity(i);

           }     
                });
```

itemName can be any string variable, not being an attribute of the View itself

Because it is defined outside of the OnCLickListener, it cannot be used inside the onClick

How can I pass itemName into the Intent so that it can be set by the 'putExtra' method?

Comment: Declare your variable as final!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define itemName as final variable, so it can be passed into anonymous classes.

```
final String itemName = menuorder[i];
...
    i.putExtra("itemName", itemName);
...
```

- it will work for you.